# Replacing views dynamically without changing activity

Tags: android, view

I would like to know how to go about doing this small problem that I am encountering while making a video player app. [image: First]

On clicking the first control(the rectangular icon) in the above image the following view must be displayed instead of it which I am quite unsure as to how to do it. Here is what it is replaced by
[image: Second]

Also please note, by any chance the activity should not be changed. I have been able to design the views individually but having problem changing them at runtime when user clicks. Could someone go about explaining as to how it can be done or provide some suitable links to achieve my goal. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something as simple as this you can just change the visibility of the views.

```
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Or the more effective:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Do that on the views you want gone, I suggest a wrapper class. It's either this or changing the contentView as describded below.

Comment: +1. But you should really use `View.GONE` to actually remove the buttons. `View.INVISIBLE` will make them invisible, but tehy still take up space.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.newLayoutToUse);
```

However, I have a feeling there is a better way to do what you want.  It's overkill to load a complete new layout if you just want to change the image of some buttons or imageviews.

Comment: this basically sets the view of the activity with the new layout but I want only a small portion of the already existing view to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid solution, 'cause i'm terribly tired right now, but why not use the `bringToFront()` method on the `View` that you want to display in the front? Display them both in front of each other, maybe in a `RelativeLayout`, and then swap between them as you wish. 
They are small objects, so don't consume memory. I don't see why this shouldn't work.

OR

Place them above one another, so they overlap and then make the above view visible/invisible depending on which one you need to display.

OR

just remembered I read somewhere that you can scroll through a `ScrollView` automatically from code. So display both `Views` in a `ScrollView` in succession and when pressing the button or whatever, you scroll down to make the next menu visible. When pres back, you scroll up to make the previous thing available. Should work, and might also make a nice animation between changing of the menus.